# Partially broken LCD missing segments

Tags: lcd

This cordless phone just started not showing some of the segments of the display (here it should show NS AMERICA). I thought those segments were just broken, however sometimes they are all working again for days, then they disappear again.

The charge level doesn't make a difference, or having it connected or disconnected from the charger.

What could be the cause for this and can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: [Zebra strip](http://www.sateco.ch/bilder/zebra_farbig.png)

Comment: It's called liquid crystal display, not 7-seg display.

Comment: most likely zebra strips do not make proper contact. Open the device with caution and realign them.

Comment: @thece "do not make proper contact" is correct, "realign them" is wrong. With few exceptions elastomeric connectors have much finer spacing than contacts they connect. They do not need to be aligned to work.

Comment: @golimar: You can see with the characters that you have shown that there are more than seven segments per character. I suspect that there are 14. See [Fourteen-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteen-segment_display). In any case, the number of segments is not relevant to the problem but the fact that it's liquid crystal is. We've fixed the title and the tag. Maple is pointing you on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite common failure of [elastomeric connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector). I had five or six cordless sets and other devices with LCD failing exactly same way.

Try the following:

- Clean the contacts. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTulo_SIE6E) for how it's done;
- After installing LCD back find a way to press it harder down onto the strip. For example use a self-adhesive tape to make a shim between the edge of the LCD and phone bezel. Sometimes LCD is installed in the plastic support panel that can be lowered a bit (fraction of a millimeter is all you need).
- If the above did not help, open it up again and flip the connector strip then try assembling/shimming again

If nothing of the above helps you can try buying a suitably-sized replacement zebra strip online, but AFAIK they are hard to find and/or sold in bulk.